# a = '3' , b = '4' ... How to change from char to numeric without changing any value?

Tags: java

```
public class Exer4 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char a = '3';
        char b = '4';
        char c = '2';
        int resultat;
        resultat = a*b/c;

        System.out.println("Result of "+a+"*"+b+"/"+c+" = "+ resultat);
    }
}
```

I want the result as: 6 (as it is 3 * 4/2) but it is not.

Comment: If you want to compute then why are you going to use `char`??

Comment: @Anubhab Look at the first line: "public class Exer4", this is homework

Comment: can you tell us what is the result that you get

Comment: Resultat de 3*4/2 = 53

Comment: Java is interpreting char differently you have to convert char values using Integer.parseInt() it's not done implicitly.

Answer (score 5):

Since it is homework, I won't divulge the solution. However, you should look into `Integer.parseInt()`.

Answer (score 1):

You should assign your variables as `int a = 3`, etc., since they are integer values instead of characters.  The character `'3'` is not the same as the integer `3`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse them as `int`s.
Try the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char a = '3';
    char b = '4';
    char c = '2';
    int resultat;
    resultat = Integer.parseInt(a)* Integer.parseInt(b) / Integer.parseInt(c);

    System.out.println("Result of "+a+"*"+b+"/"+c+" = "+ resultat);
}
```

Depending on your values it might be better to parse them as `Double`.

Alternatively you can easily just use `int`s directly:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 3;
        int b = 4;
        int c = 2;
        int resultat;
        resultat = a * b / c;

        System.out.println("Result of "+a+"*"+b+"/"+c+" = "+ resultat);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Character.getNumericValue(Char a)`.
According to your problem you can do this by

```
int aa=Character.getNumericValue(a); 
int bb=Character.getNumericValue(b);
int cc= Character.getNumericValue(c);
resultat = aa*bb/cc;

System.out.println("Result of "+a+"*"+b+"/"+c+" = "+ resultat);
```